# Tracking login in user time on page on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, statistics

I have a simple informative website built in Wordpress. Users must login befor they can view pages ,I would like to track the time each user is viewing each page. Is there a simple plugin or JavaScript I can use to make a database of this information.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like the following suffice?

https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/aryo-activity-log/